# having issue with localstorage while accessing it back

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am having problem with localstorage.I am using payment gateway for my ecommerce site.Before moving on to the payment gateway I save my item to cart with the help of local storage.When I get reply from payment gateway my localstorage automatically get clean or null.
What can be the possible problem.
I am saving a list in localstorage
code

```
 var shopp = [];
shopp is a array of items
 localStorage["listShoppingCart"] = JSON.stringify(shopp);
```

this `listShoppingCart` always gets empty

Comment: you can check the value of local storage in browser tools->Resources->Local Storage

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
localStorage.setItem('listShoppingCart', JSON.stringify(shopp));
```

Also is your domain and protocol the same before and after the payment gateway?
E.g. If you go from http before to https after then the localStorage will be different

Comment: yes i am moving from https to https and then back to https

Comment: have you tested accessing `listShoppingCart` on a new page without going to the gateway?

Comment: Yes scott, I am already accessing the saqme on more than one page.Even sometimes localstorage persist and sometimes it doesnt.

Comment: Are you setting the value anywhere else in the code? You could use code like this to track all storage access.  `window.addEventListener("storage", function(e) {
   console.debug(e);
}, false);`  Maybe it is getting overwritten somewhere.